# Robot FW : builtin module : "Set Suite Variable" : How to pass the suite variable to a child test suite?

Tags: robotframework, built-in

Referring to ["Set Suite Variable" documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable)

> Possible child test suites do not see variables set with this keyword by default. Starting from Robot Framework 2.9, that can be controlled by using children= as the last argument. **If the specified  is a non-empty string or any other value considered true in Python, the variable is set also to the child suites.** Parent and sibling suites will never see variables set with this keyword.

Here is my parent suite:

```
Use "Set Suite Variable"
    [Documentation] 
    ...                 Set Suite Variable  name, *values
    ...                 Makes a variable available everywhere within 
    ...                 the scope of the current 
    ...                 suit and in the scope of the child test suites
    Set Suite Variable  @{x}     Item 1     ${2}   Item 3      # 1
    Set Suite Variable  &{y}   key=value      children=${True} # 2
```

**The goal**

The goal is to implement a basic child suite, where we check that

**A)** `@{x}` is **not** available (because we did **not** use children=${True} in the parent suite in #1).

**B)**  &{y} is available in the child test suite (Because we did use children=${True} in the parent suite in #2)

Note that in (A) and (B), child test suite should use `Variable Should Exist` keyword from builtin library.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It appears that all three tests are in one suite, so they will all be able to see both variables.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Is my Question now clear with the update?

Comment: What is the question?